# Getting a list of salesforce reports with the 'unique name' and not just the user label

Tags: reflection, reporting, salesforce

Get a manipulatable list of Salesforce reports is already a little bit convoluted, requiring login to the site and then downloading /servlet/servlet.ReportList, which is an xml file containing a list of reports. For each report you get the folder name, the name (user label), the id and whether it is public. However two fields are missing - the "unique" name and the description. The unique name is important here, as Salesforce allows any number of reports, even in the same folder, to have the same name/label. This means the only way to tell them apart is by the unique name.

Is there any way to get a list of reports that includes both the unique name and the id? (or failing that the description and the id?)

Answer (score 1):

The [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_report.htm) supports Reports.

Included are the "name"and "fullName" fields. The latter is the unique ID for a Report.